# Vue JS "scope" style does not work with SVG inner elements

Tags: css, vue.js, debugging, svg

I have a button which contains an SVG icon. I am unable to change the color inner elements of the SVG when the stylesheet is "scope"

**Component code:**

```
<template>
  <a class="my-btn">
    <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="..." fill="black" fill-opacity="0.54"/>
    </svg>
    <span>
      My Button Label
    </span>
  </a>
</template>

<style src="@/assets/css/my-custome-button.css"scope></style>
```

**CSS code (@/assets/css/my-custome-button.css)**

```
a.my-btn:hover svg path {  
    fill: red !important;
    fill-opacity: 1;
}
```

**Issue**

Because I am using the "scope" attribute in the  tag, Vue automatically assigns an attribute to the matching elements and rewrites the CSS accordingly. It appears that Vue cannot access the SVG inner elements. The final CSS looks something like:

```
a.my-btn svg path[data-v-64222e86] {  
    fill: var(--danger) !important;
    fill-opacity: .9;
}
```

but the output SVG does not include the "data-v-64222e86" attribute.

Removing the "scoped" property will address the issue, but the non-scoped CSS may affect other elements in the page (unintended result)

**Any suggestion on how to have "scoped" CSS code that can control the style of SVG elements?**

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by using the `:deep` (shorthand for `::v-deep`) selector:

```
a.my-btn:hover svg :deep(path) {  
    fill: red;
    fill-opacity: 1;
}
```

More info here: https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0023-scoped-styles-changes.md